# How do I equally place multiple divs on multiple rows?

Tags: css, sass

I'd like to place divs equally spaced on multiple rows. I've tried setting margins or justify-content but none of them worked so far. I want the course-lists in each row to be equally spaced but the space between the lists depends on the length of the name of the courses when I tried setting margins. I'm new to CSS so I'm sorry if the question or my codes are confusing.

HTML

```
        <div className="course-section">
          <div>
            <h2 id="course-tag">Coursework</h2>
          </div>
          <div className="course-box">
            <div className="course-list-row">
              <div className="course-bullet"></div>
              <div className="course-list">Data Structures</div>
              <div className="course-bullet"></div>
              <div className="course-list">Computer Architecture</div>
            </div>
            <div className="course-list-row">
              <div className="course-bullet"></div>
              <div className="course-list">Numerical Analysis</div>
              <div className="course-bullet"></div>
              <div className="course-list">Numerical Methods</div>
            </div>
            <div className="course-list-row">
              <div className="course-bullet"></div>
              <div className="course-list">Discrete Structures</div>
              <div className="course-bullet"></div>
              <div className="course-list">Intro to Computer Science</div>
            </div>
            <div className="course-list-row">
              <div className="course-bullet"></div>
              <div className="course-list">Applied Linear Algebra</div>
              <div className="course-bullet"></div>
              <div className="course-list">Physics Courses</div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
```

CSS

```
@mixin bullet {
  height: 15px;
  width: 15px;
  background-color: blue;
  display: inline-block;
}

@mixin resume-box {
  background-color: white;
  height: 350px;
  width: 700px;
  margin: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 15px 3px #b0abaa;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 15px 3px #b0abaa;
  box-shadow: 0 0 15px 3px #b0abaa;
}

.course-section {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    flex-direction: column;

    #course-tag {
      margin-bottom: 40px;
      margin-right: 530px;
      font-weight: bold;
      font-size: 30px;
    }
    .course-box {
      @include resume-box;
      margin-bottom: 80px;
      padding: 40px 50px 40px 50px;
    }

    .course-bullet {
      @include bullet;
    }

    .course-list {
      display: inline-block;
      margin-left: 10px;
      font-size: 20px;
    }

    .course-list-row {
      margin-bottom: 20px;
    }
  }
```

[image: I want something like this]

It's what I want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I think it can be simplyfied like this:

HTML:

```
<div class="course-section">
  
  <div>
    <h2 id="course-tag">Coursework</h2>
  </div>
  
  <div class="course-box">
    
    <div class="course-list">Data Structures</div>
    <div class="course-list">Computer Architecture</div>
    <div class="course-list">Numerical Analysis</div>
    <div class="course-list">Numerical Methods</div>
    <div class="course-list">Applied Linear Algebra and lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</div>
    <div class="course-list">Discrete Structures</div>
    <div class="course-list">Intro to Computer Science</div>
    <div class="course-list">Physics Courses</div>
    
  </div>
  
</div>
```

scss:

```
@mixin bullet {
  height: 15px;
  width: 15px;
  background-color: blue;
  display: inline-block;
}

@mixin resume-box {
  background-color: white;
  height: 350px;
  width: 700px;
  margin: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  box-shadow: 0 0 15px 3px #b0abaa;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.course-section {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;

  #course-tag {
    margin-bottom: 40px;
    margin-right: 530px;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 30px;
  }
  
  .course-box {
    @include resume-box;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    padding: 40px 50px 40px 50px;
    
    .course-list {
      flex: 0 0 50%;
      position: relative;
      font-size: 20px;
      padding-left: 35px;

      &:before {
        content: '';
        position: absolute;
        left: 10px;
        top: 3px;
        @include bullet;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The important things here are:

```
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Flex does not really need this, but i usually use this `box-sizing` so margins and paddings won't get sum to dom elements total height and/or width. I find `border-box` to be more precise.

```
.course-box {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```

The container is set to flex so we can use the flex property of its child elements to have them aligned and distributed. `flex-wrap: wrap` basically does what it says, force content inside a flex container to wrap when width is reached. (try to put it as `nowrap` in the snippet and see what happens)

```
.course-list {
      flex: 0 0 50%;
}
```

Finally, we set the flex property of the list elements to `0 0 50%`, this basically translates into **0** (this element can't be shrinked) **0** (this element can't be expanded) **50%** (width of the element). So if you would like to have 3 elements per row it would be `0 0 33%` and so.

You could even make it responsive. For example:

```
.course-list {
    flex: 0 0 50%;

    @media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
        flex: 0 0 100%;
    }
}
```

this would result into two column rows in desktop and one column rows in mobile.

Also, avoid use a div to fake a bullet, better use the :after or :before pseudo elements as the snippet below, it will result in much cleaner html.

Here is a snippet:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.course-section {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.course-section #course-tag {
  margin-bottom: 40px;
  margin-right: 530px;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 30px;
}

.course-section .course-box {
  background-color: white;
  height: 350px;
  width: 700px;
  margin: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  box-shadow: 0 0 15px 3px #b0abaa;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  padding: 40px 50px 40px 50px;
}

.course-section .course-box .course-list {
  flex: 0 0 50%;
  position: relative;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding-left: 35px;
}

.course-section .course-box .course-list:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: 10px;
  top: 3px;
  height: 15px;
  width: 15px;
  background-color: blue;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="course-section">

  <div>
    <h2 id="course-tag">Coursework</h2>
  </div>

  <div class="course-box">

    <div class="course-list">Data Structures</div>
    <div class="course-list">Computer Architecture</div>
    <div class="course-list">Numerical Analysis</div>
    <div class="course-list">Numerical Methods</div>
    <div class="course-list">Applied Linear Algebra and lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</div>
    <div class="course-list">Discrete Structures</div>
    <div class="course-list">Intro to Computer Science</div>
    <div class="course-list">Physics Courses</div>

  </div>

</div>
```